# How post to facebook fun page by api?

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

Hi i have a problem with Facebook API. I use Graph Api method /page-id/feed [message] => ''
But it posted not in timeline, and from my account name. But i need post it from name of fun page name.

Comment: You'll need to use a [Page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) in order to perform actions on behalf of the page. Currently you are using a user access token and this is why the post is created from your account.

Comment: I try it, it give to me access_token of my account, not page

Comment: You need to request the page token first and only after that you can use it with your requests. Use your user access token to look at this URL: `/{user-id}/accounts` - from there you'll be able to extract the page access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a [Page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) in order to perform actions on behalf of the page. Currently you are using a user access token and this is why the post is created from your account